# Multiple translations in a single reStructuredtext file

Tags: multilingual, restructuredtext, docutils, rst2html.py

Is there a way to achieve the following?

- Source is a single `.rst` file where the translation in multiple languages coexist
- Generate web page renditions per language (in `.html` files preferably).

  - This can be either a single file where readers can switch between languages, or multiple separate .html files
- Preferably web page generation can be done by `rst2html` but other common tools are welcomed as well

Usecase I have in mind. In `foo.rst` (I don't mean I want exactly tags like these):

```
..lang_en:

  She likes spinach the best.

..lang_de:

  Sie mag am besten Spinat.
```

Result would be, as I mentioned, either a single `foo.html`, or a set of `foo_en.html` and `foo_de.html`.

Comment: funny I am looking into exact the same thing. I looked into pelican but it can not handle translations in one file out of the box. Looks like I have to write a plugin for this. Currently I am looking into docutils and I believe I can use its Node-Interface to implement this. Please let me know if you found a solution already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out by using [sphinx-intl](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/intl.html); it creates folders per language, and update the translations based on the change in the master file take a few steps (which requires careful operation), but I'm satisfied.

If you need a concrete example, in [this project](https://github.com/tork-a/openrtm_tutorial/blob/devel/README.rst) holds I'm maintaining English and Japanese renditions.